# How can I avoid taking users to www.website.com/filename.php after they submit a form?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, refresh

I was wondering if anyone knows how to automatically refresh a webpage after clicking on a form submit button rather than being taken to a .php page?

Here's my html:

```
<p>
<form action='action.php' method='post'>
<textarea name='message' rows='3' cols='30'>
</textarea><br><br>
<input type='SUBMIT' value='Submit' />  
</p>
```

Here's my php:

```
<?php 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
mail("name@website.com","", $message)
?>
```

Any help much appreciated,

Guy Brown

Comment: You could submit with `JS` or redirect from your `PHP` page... Which do you prefer?

Comment: You can use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in action attribute of your form tag

Comment: JS or PHP, which ever has the minimal code... where in the code would I put $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ? doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can do it in same file where form is located like this (if form is located in action.php or change action.php to php self as suggested):

```
<p>
  <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'>
    <textarea name='message' rows='3' cols='30'>
    </textarea><br><br>
    <input type='SUBMIT' value='Submit' />  
  </form>
</p>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['message'])) {
  $message = $_POST['message']; 
  mail("name@website.com","", $message)
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but I got the following echoed before the textbox: ' method='post'>